# Rails, How to remove validates_attachment_content_type for Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

I am using paperclip to allow users have their own avatar. I notice that when I go to active admin to either edit or create a new user I get an "avatar content type is invalid error" in the avatar content type field when that user does not have an avatar.

I can overcome this error by typing in image/jpeg in the field but obviously this would not be ideal for other admin users to have to type that in every time they want to create or edit a user.

User.rb

```
....   has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
      validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/....
```

Is there a way to keep validation but turn it off for active admin by hiding the field or some other method? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to use a virtual attribute to skip image validation.

In User model:

```
# models/user.rb
attr_accessor :skip_image_validation

validates_attachment_content_type :avatar ... , unless: lambda { skip_image_validation.present? }
```

And in active admin's before_save callback, assign `:skip_image_validation` to true like

```
# admin/user.rb
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  before_save do |user|
    user.skip_image_validation = true
  end
...
```

Comment: Cool this works. Thanks very much. Just wondering though is there any risk with this?

Comment: Using a virtual attribute is a very common technique to skip validation in Rails. Outside activeadmin, `skip_image_validation` is nil, so `validates_attachment_content_type` will always be called.

Comment: undefined local variable or method `skip_image_validation' for #<User:0xd734408> - i'm getting this error when I try update profile pic for a user in my main edit user page??

Comment: I'm not sure how you update the profile pic. You could ask another question, then we'll look into it.

Comment: I'm using devise and it says the error is in registrations controller. This actually caused me a lot of pain because when I removed validation my user account was automatically cancelled on update. I will open a new question tomorrow - hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to customize your `create` and `update` methods in admin. For example:

```
controller do
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.assign_attributes(params[:user], as: :admin)
    @user.save(validate: false)
    redirect_to edit_admin_user_path(@user), :notice => "User Account Updated"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it does not seem to work. What model am I putting it in to? I tried admin_user and user.rb in active admin. Do I have to remove params.permit! to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Should be in `user.rb` in `activeadmin`. You don't have to remove `params.permit!`

Comment: Thanks, nearly there! "Couldn't find User with 'id'="   :/

Comment: Did you try to create a new user or update a user? The code above is just a sample for updating.

Comment: I tried to create a new user. When I tried update I get a 2 for 1 arguments error in update in user.rb

Comment: I can't remember. I'd have to do it again to find out. Happy to do it if your interested to know. I think it was the second line.

Comment: It was exactly what I had in one of my projects. The only thing I can come up with is probably we define `edit_admin_user_path` in different ways.

Comment: I raked routes and it's the same. Bizarre.

Comment: I do have another issue though in that the encrypted password does not show in it's field when I am editing a user. This means I have to copy and paste another encrypted password in to the field every time I edit a user. Don't know why that is.